# Form new Datatable by using existing new Datatable based on values

Tags: c#, datatable

I have one datatable which is filled by sql query and its having ID,subject,Description

[image]

Based on the subject and description value I need to form the datatable following like,

[image]

for the Ids 123,234 values are having the same Subject and description so i need to merged as single row and need to set the two Id values in single ID column .

How can I achieve this ? Is it possible ? Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: member for 5 years, and with 700+ rep. I'd expect you to make an attempt....

Comment: @mitch wheat i tried a lot by using Merge rows and all .. Id idnt achieve that after that i posted here

Comment: you tried a lot, but decided not to show any attempts? weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 123, "Test", "Test" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 234, "Test", "Test" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 456, "Test 1", "Test1" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 789, "Test 1", "Test1" });

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));

            dt2 = dt1.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Subject"))
                .Select(x => dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Field<int>("ID").ToString()).ToArray()),
                        x.Key,
                        x.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("Description")
                    })).CopyToDataTable();

        }
    }
}
```